# How to customize the "Hello and welcome" default response message in Microsoft Azure Bot QnA framework

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to make a chatbot using Microsoft Azure web app bot design for QnA bot (using QnA maker for the knowledgebase. I found out how to rewrite in code default response message "no good match in FAQ". Isn't it possible to rewrite similar way also the "Hello and Welcome" default message somewhere in the code?[This is how I changed the "no good match in FAQ" default message in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kymdo.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and Hilton Giesenow is correct, under Bots>QnAbot.cs

Please see [this screenshot to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUAAO.jpg)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps.

Answer (score 9):

If someone is looking to customize the welcome message in the latest version (as of  Feb 03, 2023) of Azure Cognitive Services - Language Services, it can be done by adding an environment variable `"DefaultWelcomeMessage"` in the app service. 
Here is how to do it-
When you are done creating your Knowledge Base (KB) in the Language Studio, and deploy it. The next step is to create a bot and test it.
With that step, Azure also creates an app service that hosts the bot.
To change the default welcome message, go to the app service resource:
 `Azure Portal -> your app service -> configuration -> Application settings -> New application setting`

```
Name  : DefaultWelcomeMessage
Value : <Your custom welcome message>
```

Comment: In case anyone is confused where to find where <your app service> is, just go to resources and check the resources list, check out the type there. It should write App Service.

Comment: Or follow the steps to override Web.config or appsettings.json as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can post some code of the bot itself where this message exactly occurs, but generally this kind of "welcome" message is handled in the [OnMembersAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler.onmembersaddedasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) event handler. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#detect-and-greet-newly-connected-users) as an example and you should have something similar in your project. I would guess without seeing more of your application that it's in your "QnABot.cs" file.