# Removing the "None of the above" option from my Azure chat bot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, chatbot, language-studio

When testing my bot in Language Services it does not offer multiple choices to ambiguous questions.
When using it after deployment, it does. I am fairly certain this is being caused by the App Service.

While I like this feature, the "None of the above." option just results in the bot saying "Thanks for the feedback", which I think isn't useful.
I'd either like to customise the response, or, remove "None of the above" entirely

[chat excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyshm.png)

After finding this [How to customize the "Hello and welcome" default response message in Microsoft Azure Bot QnA framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288336/how-to-customize-the-hello-and-welcome-default-response-message-in-microsoft-a) I believe the error lies in the App Service, but it is not clear on what needs to be changed